# SQL Numeros Decimales redondeados

Tags: sql, sql-server

En SQL por dar un ejemplo en algunos campos me arrojan datos como "300.38383 " por dar un ejemplo y yo solo necesito las 2 primeras decimales después del punto`redondeadas

> Que funciones hay para que solo arroje las 2 primeras decimales redondeadas

Comment: Estas buscando la funcion format?

Comment: acaso te sería útil la función round();

Comment: En el de SELECT ROUND(123.4567, 2) me arroja123.4600 yo lo que necesito solo es que muestre 123.45 tomando ese ejemplo

Answer (score 3):

Para formatear numeros en sql server, podes usar la funcion FORMAT

> FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )

La función recibe el valor, y el tipo de formato. Para formatos numericos, a dos decimales, podes usar un formato estandar como 'N', que formatea a dos decimales automaticamente.

```
Format(300.38383,'N')
```

Devolvera

> 300.38

Como referencia, esta la documentación [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: +1 Y como observación también puede usar: `Format(300.38383,'N2')` :)